# open Pdf document in C# in Window application

Tags: c#, pdf

I am creating a pdf in `C#`. it is successful created and store in my drive but now I open that created pdf using on button click on my window form.

How can I do this.

I am using `AcropdfLib` but in that there is no `show()` method found.

Comment: You should show the code you're using. Also, not everyone in the world knows about this AcropdfLib you're talking about. Provide a link to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you want to open the created PDF ? Just open the PDF file separately or open within windows form ?

`Just to Open PDF file`

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\eBook.pdf";
process.Start();
```

`Load PDF within windows form`

You can use WebBrowser control to load PDF by passing file path to `Navigate()`

```
private void OpenPdf(string filePath)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of them work! Great! But, in second solution, Neither it does open the file in web browser control nor it does open outside the web browser control in any case when it's compiled in x64 or ANY CPU... it is the only side effect!

Comment: @Kurubaran: webBrowser1 is object of what?  Sorry i am new at this things and i didn't get it.

Comment: @ParthRuparelia it's the name of the WebBrowser control in the windows form.

Comment: If using net core have to add process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;